# ASA 5585-X IPS-SSP image recovery?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, intrusion-prevention

ASA 5585-X with SSP-10 and IPS-SSP 60

Slot 0:SSP-10 works fine

Slot 1:IPS-SSP-60 is not responsive, ports not coming up, show module cannot detect software version, boot image missing

Management 0/0 on SSP-10 is connected to tftp server. I can download the image from tftp to CF.

The image recovery procedure in Cisco documentations say there is no way to directly set boot image for IPS SSP. I have to use tftp in rommon or put the module in recovery mode.

I set recovery config and put the module into recovery mode but console on IPS SSP still shows boot loop because no valid image found.

1) I know SSP-10 + IPS-SSP 60 is not supported by TAC. Does this work at all? ports can stay up for only 20 seconds on IPS-SSP

2) Why management interfaces on IPS SSP not showing up as management 1/0, 1/1?

3) Do I need to connect IPS SSP's management port to tftp server (SSP's management port already connected to tftp server)? Then how do I reference the management ports on IPS SSP since they are not shown in #show interface ip brief

Can someone give me some hints why the recovery is not working? Apparently I can't open a case with TAC for this issue.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Cisco documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/ips/7.1/installation/guide/hw_installing_ssp.pdf): "The ASA 5585-X IPS SSP must be at the same level as the ASA 5585-X SSP model; for example, if you have the ASA 5585-X with SSP-10, you can only install the IPS SSP-10."

So, generally to answer your questions:

1) No, it should not be possible, and somewhere in the logging or debugging it will probably tell you that it is disabling the IPS-SSP because it isn't compatible; or it will show that the SSP is trying to transfer an incompatible image to the IPS-SSP.

2) If the module is disabled (or booting), the interfaces generally won't be shown.

3) This is really a moot point since you probably won't be able to do anything at all with the IPS-SSP if it is disabled or not booted entirely.